# Can YouTube be embedded in Android Applications? How about WebOS or Blackberry?

Tags: iphone, android, video, youtube, webos

Can YouTube videos be played from within an AndroidOS without launching the separate YouTube player? How about WebOS or Blackberry?

On the iPhone I can do this with a WebView and the embedded YouTube code and I'm weighing the possibility of porting my app to other mobile platforms. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. webview.setPluginsEnabled(true);

Answer (score 1):

You can launch the webOS YouTube player from your app in a separate card using code like:

```
launchYouTube: function(mediaURL)
{
  var params = {
    target: mediaURL,
    direct: true
  };
  this.controller.serviceRequest('palm://com.palm.applicationManager', {
    method:'launch',
    parameters: {
      'id': 'com.palm.app.youtube',
      'params': params
  });
}
```

The mediaURL parameter looks like "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_6U9YGDtSEs" depending on the video.

As best I can tell, the YouTube player does not support the sublaunch mechanism that allows it to be embedded as a new scene on your own app's stage.

Comment: can you explain what you mean about the mediaURL para? Is it like `mediaURL = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_6U9YGDtSEs",`

Answer (score 0):

setPluginsEnabled is now deprecated, new method:

```
webView.getSettings().setPluginState( WebSettings.PluginState.ON );
```

Comment: This is deprecated starting in API 18